# RDP file shortcut prompts for password popup

Tags: rdp

I made several attempts to set up the RDP file in the GPO and keep asking for a password.

I am using a RDP Remote App in Windows 2019 version.

I want to use the passwords of the login already authenticated in the domain.

Thank you.

[Popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfYs5.jpg)

[Configured file rdp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhyU6.jpg)

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/584876/how-do-i-use-my-current-credentials-with-remote-desktop